# How to use python3 to connect to a ipv6 host using socket library

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ipv6

The following is my code in an attempt to connect to an IPv6 address host using sockets in python. However, all my attempts have resulted in the output "Network is unreachable". Could you point out what I am doing wrong and how it could be corrected?

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('2001:240:2408:8897:b4ac:9e51:ecc9:a388',8333,0,0))
```

**OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable net
work**

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you did wrong is to give an IP address and port which is not reachable. It is also not reachable by other tools like telnet or netcat. The syntax itself is the correct one to connect to an IPv6 server. It will successfully connect if your for example replace the IP address with one for google.com and the port with 80 (http):

```
sock.connect(('2a00:1450:4001:81c::200e',80,0,0))
```

Comment: I tried connecting to IPv6 address of google, using the code you typed above. However, I still encounter a timeout error saying that connection couldn't be established

https://imgur.com/EtoezT6

Comment: @SajanMaharjan: I doubt that this is a Python problem then. It is more likely that IPv6 connections from your systems are generally restricted. Have you've tried other ways outside Python to make sure that IPv6 works in the first place?

Comment: How do I make sure that check if IPv6 is working? I tried with [test-ipv6](https://test-ipv6.com) and it results in saying IPv6 connectivity is not working? How do I enable IPv6? I have tried adding a manual IPv6 address using netsh command line, but still can't find a way to figure this one out. Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: @SajanMaharjan: *"How do I enable IPv6?"* - this is a different question and should not be asked in a comment. And it would not be on-topic at stackoverflow.com since it is unrelated to programming - superuser.com would be a better fit. It is also not a trivial question. And it will not be sufficient to add IPv6 to your local system. If you want to reach external systems by IPv6 your ISP needs to provide you with proper IPv6 connectivity in the first place and many still don't.